# How would you calculate the point size of a font necessary to best fit a predefined area?

Tags: c#, graphics, fonts, font-size, dpi

I have an interesting problem.  I'm almost there but am curious how others would tackle it.  I want to display some multi-line text in a predefined area.  I don't know what the text will be or how big the area will be so the function would have to be written generically. You can assume a standard font is always used but the point size is what must change.

Assume you have a function that will draw text that is passed to it in a string parameter.  The function has a form object to draw in, and is also passed a rectangle object defining the bounding area of the text on the form.  The function needs to display the text on the form in the given rectangle in as large a font as will fit.  The challenge for me was is in calculating the size of the font to use to have the text fit as best it can, in the rectangle with minimal white space.

These 2 equations might be useful:

```
float pixels = (points *dpi)/72f;
float points = (pixels*72f)/dpi);
```

Also:

```
float dpi = CreateGraphics().DpiY;
```

Comment: Wow, looking at the suggestions thus far, I didn't realize the last bit was going to be so iterative!  What if we assume that text is NOT wrapped.  A hard return would break up the multiple lines so we only have to worry about the longest line for width.

Answer (score 2):

Well, it is tricky.  Calculating a point size directly isn't going to work, the width of the text is dependent on the font metrics.  Binary search is an obvious strategy but it cannot work in practice.  True-type hinting and word wrapping conspire to destabilize it.

I'd recommend you start with binary search, setting hi and lo to reasonable defaults like 72 and 6.  Then when the range narrows down to, say, 5 points, start testing each individual point size until you find the largest one that fits.  When you write the algorithm, do make sure you count on a size N that fits but a size N-1 that doesn't fit.

Comment: Would not allowing word wrap make it easier?

Comment: Yes, much less likely for binary search to fail.  But not zero due to hinting.  Stop searching when the range is less than 1 point btw.

Answer (score 2):

There is a significant problem with any solution, which is you need to determine this based on the width as well, which is completely dependent upon the font. This means you need to calculate the width of each word independently based on a predefined point size font. As you change the point size, it is not guaranteed to be consistent.

***The solution won't be fast if you want it to be accurate.***

I would suggest selecting two point sizes (say 6 and 18) that represent the smallest and mid- to high-point and compute the pixel width of each word in each point size. You could then compute the area of both sizes of text.

You could then extrapolate the area of the rectangle you find appropriate and determine the target size (width and height) using an arbitrary width/height ratio based on the length of text - there is an optimum readable width, for instance.

You will then need to iteratively attempt to word-wrap inside the rectangle and work backwards in point size until the text fits within the rectangle.

Comment: What if we don't take into account word wrap. We'll assume newlines break up the lines and no one line will extend beyond the rectangle

Comment: The important thing is to calculate the width first and don't change it once calculated, you can then use the width to limit the length of lines and end up with a rectangle that will (probably) be one or two extra lines tall. It doesn't always look good, but newspaper columns use a carefully calculated column width to allow maximum readability. Go with US Letter or A4 ratio rectangles (around 1.3:1). Also, the array of word widths would be helpful in quickly iterating solutions.

Answer (score 0):

binary search over point sizes:
Start with the biggest available point size. If it doesn't fit, try half of that, ...

Comment: How would you determine a "fit"?